# Importing a specific list of elements from a website to a python list

Tags: python, html, pandas, list, python-requests

Hi i'm new to this site i would like to know if there is a way to import all the 80k+ tickers from this site https://www.gurufocus.com/stocks in a single python list.
Example output `print(tickers.[0])` could be something like this `&Do Holdings Co Ltd`

I have tried to use the following solution

```
import pandas as pd


tickers = pd.read_html("https://www.gurufocus.com/stocks")[0]['Tickers']
print(tickers)
```

but i get error 403

Does anyone know how can i import all the 80k tickers from this particular website?

Comment: You have to consider why you're getting HTTP 403 (Forbidden). Almost certainly due an authentication issue. Also, you'll probably want to use selenium due to the JS implementation on that site

Comment: They obviously know you're a bot, They're using Cloudflare. You'll have to use a library that gets around this, like Cloudscraper on Github.

Comment: Do you have any code snippet or a code example?